# Show $(abcde)$ is the cube of a $5$-cycle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

Show $(abcde)$ is the cube of a $5$-cycle.

Let $x^3= (abcde).$

$$x^3 =
\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d & e \\ b & c & d & e & a\end{pmatrix} =  (abcde)$$

Taking inverse, get:

$$x^{-3} =
\begin{pmatrix} b & c & d & e & a \\ a & b & c & d & e\end{pmatrix} = (baedc)$$

There seems no way to take out $x$ from either $x^3$ or $x^{-3}$?

Comment: If $x$ is a 5-cycle, what’s $x^6$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Cannot understand the hint. Please elaborate. Seems $6$ has some link with cycle length. But how, is unclear?

Comment: So, for a cycle of length $n$  need $n+1$ powers to bring it back to start state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(abcde)=(acebd)^3$

To get $\sigma^n$, where $\sigma$ is a cycle, just "jump $n$-times".

---

Or, using the hint, you just need $(abcde)^2$.

Comment: Hope by 'hint', must mean that given by @JamieRedcliffe. But simply taking $x^6= (x^3)^2=x^3 =
\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d & e \\ c & d & e & a & b\end{pmatrix} \implies (acebd)$ is not helping, unless link between cycle length and power of permutation be known.

Comment: We get $x^6=x$.

Comment: Thanks. So, need assumption of a cyclic group, so taking any power will not create disjoint cycles?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a $5$-cycle $x=(x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ x_5)$. We want $x^3=(a\ b\ c\ d\ e)$, that is, $$x^3=(x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ x_5)^3=(x_1\ x_4\ x_2\ x_5\ x_3)=(a\ b\ c\ d\ e).$$ One solution is $x_1=a$, $\ x_2=c$, $\ x_3=e$, $\ x_4=b$, $\ x_5=d$,
so $x=(a\ c\ e\ b\ d)$.

Comment: How is it sure that disjoint cycles would not arise on taking cube of a cycle? Say, for $x=(123456), x^2=(135)(246)$. If elements are $3z,z\in\mathbb{N},$ then cube will give disjoint cycles.

Comment: You were asked to find a $5$-cycle $x$ whose cube is $1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$. If $(x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ x_5)^3$ had turned out not to be a $5$-cycle, your answer would be "there is no solution."

Comment: A power of an $n$-cycle will take the form of a prodoct of $h$ disjoint $k$-cycles where $hk=n$. For example, the square of a $6$-cycle is the product of $2$ disjoint $3$-cycles. If $p$ is a prime number, any power of a $p$-cycle is either a $p$-cycle or the identity permutation; it will be the identity if the exponent is a multiple of $p$.  In the case at hand, $5$ is a prime number and $3$ is not a multiple of $5$, so it was predictable that the cube of a $5$-cycle would be a $5$-cycle. Not that you needed to know that to solve your problem.